# Calculating Averages based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this table.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to calculate the average based on column B and put the value in this table.

[image]

In other words, in E4 I want to put the average of all rows where column B contained a value of 26.

The formula I have to calculate this is:

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS('BDA Audit'!$S5:$S10393, 'BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393, Statistiques!F$3)/COUNTIF('BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393,  Statistiques!F$3),"")
```

I also want to calculate the average YTD. That is the average of all rows from week 1 to the current week.

I tried to do this with

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS('BDA Audit'!$S5:$S10393, 'BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393, <= Statistiques!F$3)/COUNTIF('BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393,  <= Statistiques!F$3),"")
```

But the formula is not happy with the "<=".

To calculate the average by area (column E), I have this

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS('BDA Audit'!$S$5:$S$10393, 'BDA Audit'!$E$5:$E$10393, Statistiques!$A7)/COUNTIF('BDA Audit'!$E$5:$E$10393,  Statistiques!$A7),"")
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct.

In addition I must retrieve the rows with the top 10 scores.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<=` must be wrapped in quotes and appended to the cell reference with an `&` sign

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS('BDA Audit'!$S5:$S10393, 'BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393, "<=" & Statistiques!F$3)/COUNTIF('BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393,  "<=" & Statistiques!F$3),"")
```

This would be a lot easier and shorter with AverageIFs

```
=averageifs('BDA Audit'!$S5:$S10393, 'BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393, "<=" & Statistiques!F$3)
```

You can add more criteria to break down into categories.

```
=averageifs('BDA Audit'!$S5:$S10393, 'BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393, "<=" & Statistiques!F$3,'BDA Audit'!$E5:$E10393, "<=" & Statistiques!$A7)
```

Of course, the value in `Statistiques!$A7` must be a perfect match for the values in `'BDA Audit'!$E5:$E10393`. If there are leading spaces in `Statistiques!$A7`, for example, but not in the BDA Audit sheet, then there won't be a match.

For more details see the [Support page for AverageIFS.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

Comment: Thanks a lot @teylyn.  AVERAGEIFS works for one condition.  If I try to add a second condition, it doesn't.  =AVERAGEIFS('BDA Audit'!$S5:$S10393, 'BDA Audit'!$B5:$B10393, "<=" & Statistiques!E$3, 'BDA Audit'!$E5:$E10393, Statistiques!$A7)

Comment: It doesn't either if I remove the leading spaces in column A.

Comment: Check that the condition cell values are actually found in the source data. Double check that there are actually matches and not cells that just "look" the same.